# Use text and images in a Google Sheets header/footer

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Docs I can apply a header and footer which can contain custom text or images to a doc.

In Google Sheets I can see how to apply a footer but it seems to only allow me to use standard data such as page number , sheet title etc, is it possible to use custom text and images in a Google Sheets header/footer?

Answer (score 1):

After invoking print preview by **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`P`</kbd>** you can **Edit custom fields** under **Headers & footers**

[image]

There you can add your custom text.

For an image, you can use **`=IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/HC08Fqe.png?1"; 3)`** and place it under **Frozen rows** which can act like custom header if you select to repeat them.

Otherwise, you can create fully custom headers/footers simply by counting rows.

Comment: thanks i tried that but couldnt get the image to output, rather it just outs the formula instead (see screenshot here) any ideas where im going wrong ? https://imgur.com/a/o8ouSdV

Comment: Here is my setup page : https://imgur.com/a/HYYRGfz

Comment: @sam for that image you need to put it under "frozen rows" not "headers&footers"

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the image in the rows where the header will be and it will show in all the sheets when you choose repeat frozen rows.
I wish I could do the same with a footer, but no solution for now.

Comment: You probably haven't noticed but your answer already exists: _[for an image, you can use.... under Frozen rows.. custom header... repeat them](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119855/117311)_